Log4j to Log4j2 Migration - GetLoggerRepository
I'm working on a project to migrate legacy Log4j implementation to log4j2 implementation. It is currently using the code as below for getting logger repository. I'm not finding any equivalent for this in log4j2.23.1.
LogManager.getLoggerRepository().getThreshold().toString()
Any leads will be appreciated.

Can you add more context to your question. What is your code trying to do? The equivalent of LoggerRepository is LoggerContext, but that will not help you much.
